# How to intercept Tab press in ActiveX in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, activex

Should the keypress event be passed to an ActiveX included in IE, or does IE intercept it for the purpose of navigating between controls on the page?

The behavior I can see so far is that pressing "Tab" when in an ActiveX tabs out of the ActiveX, not passing the keypress. Did anyone have any other experience (searching doesn't help, as ActiveX looks to be a very unpopular technology nowadays).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement [IInputObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761804(VS.85).aspx).  Make sure you implement HasFocusIO() properly.